# Apply different styles to parts of the same element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider this element:

> Count Dracula: Bleh bleh bleh

I need to split the text in a way that the bit before (and including) the colon has one style (say, bold and red) and the rest has another (say, black and italics).

I am trying to do this using JQuery and here's my attempt:

```js
$("vi").each(function(){
   var temp = $(this).text();
   temp = temp.split(':');
   temp[0] = "<strong>" + temp[0].trim() + "</strong>";
   temp[1] = "<em>" + temp[1].trim() + "</em>";
   temp = temp.join("");
   $(this).text(temp);
});
```

```css
vi {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<vi>Dracula: bleh bleh bleh</vi>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this wouldn't work? When I try running it, it just outputs the text along with the tags I added as is, i.e. it displays "" instead of applying it, and so on.

Comment: Wrap respective parts of text with <span> tags. Don't make it too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.html()`, not `.text()`, since you are inserting HTML into an element:

```
$("vi").each(function(){
   var temp = $(this).text();
   temp = temp.split(':');
   temp[0] = "<strong>" + temp[0].trim() + "</strong>";
   temp[1] = "<em>" + temp[1].trim() + "</em>";
   temp = temp.join("");
   $(this).html(temp);
});
```

Also, if I'm understanding the description of what you want, your CSS style should be:

```
vi strong {
  color: red;
}
```

Note: `vi` is not a valid HTML element - but you probably already knew that.

```js
$("vi").each(function(){
   var temp = $(this).text();
   temp = temp.split(':');
   temp[0] = "<strong>" + temp[0].trim() + "</strong>";
   temp[1] = "<em>" + temp[1].trim() + "</em>";
   temp = temp.join(": ");
   $(this).html(temp);
});
```

```css
vi strong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<vi>Dracula: bleh bleh bleh</vi>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `html()` to the element. Read  http://api.jquery.com/html

```js
$("vi").each(function(){
   var temp = $(this).text();
   temp = temp.split(':');
   temp[0] = "<strong>" + temp[0].trim() + "</strong>";
   temp[1] = "<em>" + temp[1].trim() + "</em>";
   temp = temp.join(": ");
   $(this).html(temp);
});
```

```css
vi {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<vi>Dracula: bleh bleh bleh</vi>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [$.fn.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method. It is convenient to use it with a function parameter, it will run `each` loop internally for you:

```js
$("vi").html(function(_, text) {
    text = text.split(':');
    return "<strong>" + text[0].trim() + "</strong> <em>" + text[1].trim() + "</em>";
});
```

```css
vi {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<vi>Dracula: bleh bleh bleh</vi>
```